# several replacements in single regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read a set of data from a file such that it can be cast to `complex`. The entries are of the form

```
line='0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604*^-10*I\n',
```

which is supposed to be rendered as

```
'(0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604e-10j)'.
```

Hence I need to insert the pair of parentheses and change the symbols for imaginary unit and exponential notation. My clumsy solution is to perform each substitution individually,

```
re.sub("\*\^","e",re.sub("[\.]{0,1}\*I","j)",re.sub("(^)","(",line))).strip(),
```

but this is not exactly readable, or sane. Is there a way to use a single regex to do this substitution?

Comment: `re.sub("(^)","(",line)` is a masterpiece :). At least, you could just write `"(" + line`. BTW, if you replace literal text, why use regex at all?

Comment: indeed :D there is no specific reason other than me trying to learn regex. If I could end up with just a single re.sub, that would be slightly less embarrassing.

Comment: `'(' + line.replace(r'*^', 'e').replace('*I', 'J').replace('\n', ')')`

Comment: Maybe [`"({})".format(line.strip().replace("*^", "e").replace("*I", "j"))`](https://ideone.com/tL56f8) is enough?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of `re.sub("^(.*)$","^\(\1\)$")` for just the brackets, but I don't seem to be able to reproduce what was matched as `.*`. Any hope?

Comment: Because you need to use raw string literals with regexps. `r"(\1)"` should be the replacement. And the pattern must be `r"^(.*)$\n?"` because `$` matches also before the final newline in the string.

Comment: The addition of `r` was the thing I was after. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can do without a regex at all:

```
line='0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604*^-10*I\n'
print("({})".format(line.strip().replace("*^", "e").replace("*I", "j")))
# => (0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604e-10j)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/tL56f8)

A "funny" [regex way](https://ideone.com/gWUtNV) showing how to use capturing groups and check what was captured in the replacement with a lambda:

```
import re
line='0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604*^-10*I\n'
print("({})".format(re.sub(r"(\*\^)|([.]?\*I)", lambda m: "e" if m.group(1) else "j", line.strip())))
# => (0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604e-10j)
```

If Group 1 (`(\*\^)`) was matched we replace with `e`, if Group 2 matched, replace with `j`.

Note that `{0,1}` limiting quantifier means the same as `?` quantifier - 1 or 0 times.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this with regex is to make a pattern that matches the whole number and captures all the important parts in capture groups:

```
(.*?)\*\^(.*?)\*I
```

This would capture `0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604` in group 1 and `10` in group 2, so substituting with `(\1e\2j)` will give you the expected result:

```
(0.2741564350068515+2.6100840481550604e-10j)
```